# Package org.springframework.aop.framework does not exist

Tags: spring, grails

I have installed grails and am trying to compile with the default version of cache:1.1.6 and I'm getting these errors within the plugin code.

Can any one help me with which dependency is broken in the repository - I havent even used the cache yet - just defined it in BuildConfig.groovy

I understand "By default, Grails will not only get the JARs and plugins that you declare, but it will also get their transitive dependencies" so why would I have to declare the dependencies?

```
Compilation error: startup failed:
Compile error during compilation with javac.
D:\Users\ve\.grails\2.4.0\projects\demo\plugins\cache-1.1.6\src\java\grails\plugin\cache\CustomCacheKeyGenerator.java:18: error: package org.springframework.aop.framework does not exist
import org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils;
                                        ^
D:\Users\ve\.grails\2.4.0\projects\demo\plugins\cache-1.1.6\src\java\grails\plugin\cache\web\PageInfo.java:43: error: package org.springframework.aop does not exist
import org.springframework.aop.PointcutAdvisor;
                              ^
D:\Users\ve\.grails\2.4.0\projects\demo\plugins\cache-1.1.6\src\java\grails\plugin\cache\web\PageInfo.java:44: error: package org.springframework.aop does not exist
import org.springframework.aop.TargetSource;
```

Comment: You have to add the [spring-aop.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop)

Comment: @Jens: Add into which config file? I assumed this should download it's own dependencies liek Maven?

Comment: You use maven? then add it to your pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd this is with a new Grails application? It sounds like it could be a corrupt Maven cache issue. Try doing:

```
 $ rm -rf ~/.m2/repository
```

Otherwise, to declare the dependency explicitly edit `BuildConfig` and add:

```
 compile 'org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.5.RELEASE'
```

To your `dependencies` block.

Comment: I had to add the entry in Buildconfig